# no autocompletion for symfony getTable() function?

Tags: symfony1

if i use Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')-> i will have no auto completion.

isnt it better to just use User:: for autocompletion?

and of course i have to define the methods static

what is the benefit with using getTable except that i can use a non static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `User::` would need to call a static method, but the methods are all non-static, so that would be invalid code.

Read up on the [singleton pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need auto completion, you can try the plugin here: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineTableGetterPlugin

It builds a very light and fast auto-generated class and makes it possible to have code completion in all major IDE's like Eclipse PDT, Zend Studio, Net Beans.